# CSS Centering Images

Tags: css, image, center

I'm writing a mobile website and I've looked for hours at a centering problem I'm having.
The website is http://peatarian.com and you can emulate the iphone browser using [transmog](http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/mobile-web-browser-emulator.php).

The CSS can be found at [this page](http://peatarian.com/qa-theme/Mobile/qa-styles.css), but the most important parts are the following :

```
html, body {height:100%;float:center;text-align:center;}
body {background-url:url(raypeat.gif) no-repeat left top;margin:0; padding:0; text-            align:center;color:black;}
body,td,input,textarea {font-size:100%; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
a:link,a:active,a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
p {margin-top:0;}
table {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;}
```

and

```
.qa-nav-main {float:center;clear:both;border-top:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black;background-color:#B7E3DA;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;padding:10px 0px;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
.qa-nav-main-list {font-size:125%; list-style:none;margin:auto;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
.qa-nav-main-item,.qa-nav-main-item-opp {margin:auto;display:block;float:left;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
.qa-nav-main-item {display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
.qa-nav-main-item-opp {margin:auto;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
.qa-nav-main-link {color:#fff; display:block; padding:6px 10px; background-color:none;}
.qa-nav-main-selected {background-color:none; text-decoration:none;}
.qa-nav-main-hot .qa-nav-main-link {background:none;}
.qa-nav-main-hot .qa-nav-main-link:hover, .qa-nav-main-hot .qa-nav-main-selected {background:#396E63;}
```

The images are the (main) menu. If you'd turn the iphone on its side, you'd see that they aren't centered.... I've tried editing so many things in .qa-nav-main and also .qa-nav-mean-item but if I set `float:center` in the latter the menu items are all on a new line (though they are centered).

Comment: Where are images? and please mention HTML also, you did mistake here ----- body {background-url:url(raypeat.gif) no-repeat left top;margin:0; padding:0; ---
I think it should be body {background:url(raypeat.gif)

Comment: So what is the centering problem?

Comment: The images are the (main) menu. If you'd turn the iphone on its side, you'd see that they aren't centered.... I've tried editing so many things in .qa-nav-main and also .qa-nav-mean-item but if I set `float:center`in the latter the menu items are all on a new line (though they are centered).

Comment: As far as I know, there is no float:center according to the CSS standards. You could set the outer container to "text-align:center" and then wrap another container around your button-items, set it's width explicitly to the needed value and then set "margin:0 auto;" to center it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your code structure like you have it now, then just add a class to the `<span>` which contains your `<center>` which contains your buttons. The class would have the following rules:

```
display: block;
width: 200px; /* this should be the width you need, please assign your own */
margin: 0 auto;
```

To your .qa-nav-main class add the following rule:

```
text-align:center;
```

This should give you the desired effekt of your spans floating in the middle. But I would suggest that you rework your markup a bit and get rid of all the spans and center tags.

The above gives you the result depiced on the following image:
[image]

Comment: That's great, Johannes! Is there a way to do this without specifying a fixed width? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so, but if your website utilized php or any other language or a dynamic website, you can simply set inline css on the element, by actually counting the number of spans inside and setting its with to count*singleItemWith.

You could also do this on the client side using javascript.